# Text Cleaning Tool

Tags: windows-7, text-processing

[The online text tools on this page](https://www.textfixer.com/) does almost everything one may need to “clean” the text in various ways. But often I need to perform multiple of those cleanings (for example replace smart quotes with regular quotes, or vice versa, remove line breaks, remove extra white space, change case, etc.). **Is there a Windows application to do multiple cleanings all at once?** (With a single click, preferably with options.) Or a similar online tool?

Comment: could you please elaborate on what functionality you are looking for exactly? for general text editing notepad++ might suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [textcleaner.net](https://textcleaner.net)

You would paste in your text in the box at the top and after choosing your options you can press clean and everything will be applied to the text in the box.

It also offers find and replace functionality.

Sadly I am not aware of a simple way to save your settings